Use SFTP with FIDO2 SSH keys
Is there a windows FTP client that supports FIDO2 keys ? Since FileZilla uses PuTTY it doesn't work, and neither do WinSCP or OpenSFTP (the first two complain that the ssh key file isn't in a known format, OpenSFTP just hangs forever).
